# Properly set Symfony's form error rendering position

Tags: forms, symfony

I try to make a registration form in Symfony 3.4 but it makes me mad that I cannot place errors properly.

This is how I render the form itself:

```
{{ form_start(registrationForm) }}
{{ form_widget(registrationForm) }}
{{ form_end(registrationForm) }}
```

And the fields are rendered from a custom template, where I declare that errors should appear under the field:

```
{% block form_row %}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ block('form_label') }}
        {{ block('form_widget_simple') }}
        {{ block('form_error') }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

However all my errors are appearing above the whole form as `li` elements in an `ul` element. I tried to add `'error_bubbling' => false` but it won't make any difference. (The error messages come form the Assert annotations on the underlying model object.)
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I assume that you have tested that your custom template is being used on the page/template (?) If that is the case, then you might be getting generic form errors that are not connected to any specific form input field. Maybe you can dump the form errors and include that info in the question.

Comment: @ejuhja Yes, I've tested it and my fields are rendered from my custom template. After I dumped the `$form->getErrors();` as I can see the Form has 3 errors, but the children elements has the corresponding errors as well...

Comment: can you try with just `form(registrationForm)` instead of the 3 explicit form rendering rows - or by replacing `form_widget` with `form_rest`? From quick look the `form_widget` looks to be rendering all root form errors before the actual input rows (in the first rendering file I happened to check).

Comment: Thank you, the `form_rest` solved the problem.